# How can I track internal links

Tags: event-tracking

I need to track **track internal links** in my Homepage.

I have multiple banners and I need to know the most clicked banner.

I can I do it?

Comment: Hum... Need more details to help you... "Homepage" ? (HTML/js ? ... ?) "Banners" ? (Pictures ? Block ? ... ?)

Comment: UTM tracking might work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics and "event tracking" for this:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

I recommend you use it with [OverlayBI](https://www.overlaybi.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=answer4), a chrome extension which offers an autotrack feature and an overlaid visualization of the number of clicks right on the clicked element.